# Invalid HTTP status code 405: for $http.put

Tags: angularjs

I have service can use curl PUT to change a property's value:

```
curl -l -X PUT -d processed=1 "http://e9049d9.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder/update&id=1"

curl -l -X PUT -d processed=0 "http://e9049d9.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder/update&id=1"
```

I want to realize it in Angularjs:

```
        var url = "http://e9049d9.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder/update&id=" + id;
        var data = { 'processed': processed } ;
        console.log("debug", url);
        console.log("debug", data);
        $http.put(url, data)
          .success(function (response)
          {
            console.log("debug",response);
          });
```

But I got following errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://e9049d9.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder/update&id=1. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

What can I do? Thanks...

**updated**:

The problem exists in ionic serve, when I debug in my android device, the code works fine:

```
                $http({
                    method: 'PUT', // support GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
                    url: "http://e9049d9.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/restorder/update&id=" + id,
                    data: 'processed=1',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    },
                    timeout: 30000, // timeout abort AJAX
                    cache: false
                }).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                    console.log("success", data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.error("error", data);
                });
```

Comment: 405 means that method is not allowed - maybe `put` is not implemented on server side?

Comment: Hi, @rzysia, thanks for your concerns. put is implemented on server side, I can use curl to test, it's ok.

Comment: Your curl command sends a request parameter in the body, using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, whereas your JS code sends a JSON object in the body. The error code is misleading, but that's probably the problem.

Comment: Hello, @JBNizet, how should I change my JS code? thanks...

Comment: You need to set the Content-Type header of your http request to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', and the body to the string 'processed=1'.

Comment: please see my upated post, I've tried, but still get error. could you please help me how to code? thanks.

Comment: `'data: processed=1',` - try as string

Comment: @rzysia, still same error...

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in ionic serve, when I debug in my android device, the code works fine.